# Insufficient privilege when creating an index in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, indexing, privileges, ora-20000

I am trying to create an index in Oracle, my ddl :

```
create index OMD_DOCTEXT2_CTX on table_name(col_name)
indextype is ctxsys.context local
parameters ('datastore CTXSYS.FILE_DATASTORE filter ctxsys.null_filter  lexer E2LEX wordlist E2WORDLIST stoplist E2STOP section group E2GROUP') parallel 4;
```

I am getting error :

```
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10758: index owner does not have the privilege to use file or URL datastore
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle Text Documentation:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cdatadic.htm#i1006307)

> File and URL datastores enable access
>   to files on the actual database disk.
>   This may be undesirable when security
>   is an issue since any user can browse
>   the file system that is accessible to
>   the Oracle user. The FILE_ACCESS_ROLE
>   system parameter can be used to set
>   the name of a database role that is
>   authorized to create an index using
>   FILE or URL datastores. If set, any
>   user attempting to create an index
>   using FILE or URL datastores must have
>   this role, or the index creation will
>   fail.
>
> For example, the following statement
>   sets the name of the database role:
>
> ```
> ctx_adm.set_parameter('FILE_ACCESS_ROLE','TOPCAT');
> ```
>
> where TOPCAT is the role that is
>   authorized to create an index on a
>   file or URL datastore. The CREATE
>   INDEX operation will fail when a user
>   that does not have an authorized role
>   tries to create an index on a file or
>   URL datastore.

So, does your user have the necessary role?

Comment: I have the necessary permissions. 
But, I found some of the filepaths in the column are invalid, those files are missing. Thats probably the issue?

Comment: Missing files were infact the issue.